# Call japplet from jframe

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, japplet

I Designed JApplet class `manually` and I designed main class by using `Netbean Builder` which generate the code automatically by default the class will be extends JFrame. so how can I run the JApplet class from JFrame .
this JApplet code
`the problem now is buttons does not appear`
**Updated**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class GalaxyTable2 extends JFrame{ //JApplet

    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    String[] columnNames
                    = {"Phone Name", "Brief Description", "Picture", "price",
                        "Buy"};

// Create image icons
    ImageIcon Image1 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s1.png"));
    ImageIcon Image2 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s2.png"));
    ImageIcon Image3 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s3.png"));
    ImageIcon Image4 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s4.png"));
    ImageIcon Image5 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note.png"));
    ImageIcon Image6 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note2.png"));
    ImageIcon Image7 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note3.png"));

    Object[][] rowData = {
        {"Galaxy S", "3G Support,CPU 1GHz",
            Image1, 120, false},
        {"Galaxy S II", "3G Support,CPU 1.2GHz",
            Image2, 170, false},
        {"Galaxy S III", "3G Support,CPU 1.4GHz",
            Image3, 205, false},
        {"Galaxy S4", "4G Support,CPU 1.6GHz",
            Image4, 230, false},
        {"Galaxy Note", "4G Support,CPU 1.4GHz",
            Image5, 190, false},
        {"Galaxy Note2 II", "4G Support,CPU 1.6GHz",
            Image6, 190, false},
        {"Galaxy Note 3", "4G Support,CPU 2.3GHz",
            Image7, 260, false},};

    MyTable ss = new MyTable(
                    rowData, columnNames);

    // Create a table
    JTable jTable1 = new JTable(ss);

    public GalaxyTable2() {
    jTable1.setRowHeight(70);

    add(new JScrollPane(jTable1),
   BorderLayout.CENTER);
   JFrame f = new JFrame();

   this.setTitle("Galaxy Phones");
   JButton button = new JButton("Home");
  button.setSize(new Dimension(200, 500));
  button.setLocation(400, 500);
  f.getContentPane().add(button);
  JButton button2 = new JButton("Confirm");
  button2.setSize(new Dimension(100, 500));
  button2.setLocation(100, 300);
  // button2.addActionListener(null);
  f.getContentPane().add(button2);
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   this.setSize(800, 700);
  this.setLocation(300, 0);
  }
    @Override

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new AMainFrame7().setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         GalaxyTable2 b=new GalaxyTable2();
        /*
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Home");
        button.setSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        button.setLocation(400, 500);
        f.getContentPane().add(button);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Confirm");
        button2.setSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        button2.setLocation(200, 500);
        button2.addActionListener(null);
        f.getContentPane().add(button2);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Galaxy Phones");
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.getContentPane().add(f, button2);
        applet.init();
        applet.start();*/
        b.pack();

        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        b.setLocation((d.width - b.getSize().width) / 2,
                        (d.height - b.getSize().height) / 2);
        b.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and this action code in main class

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
new GalaxyTable().setVisible(true); 
dispose();
 }
```

Comment: Uh, you sure you want to call `dispose()` after creating your applet? Also, you are not adding the applet to anything...

Comment: I used `dispose` to close main class after open JApplet class which is GalaxyTable. What can I do now??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Applets are designed to be run from within the context of a browser (or applet viewer), they're not really designed to be added into other containers.

Technically, you can add a applet to a frame like any other component, but personally, I wouldn't.  The applet is expecting a lot more information to be available to it in order to allow it to work fully.

Instead, I would move all of the "application" content to a separate component, like a `JPanel` for example and simply move this between the applet or frame as required...

ps- You can use `f.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to center the window on the screen ;)

**Updated**

You need to go back to basics.  Unless you absolutely must have one, avoid applets until you understand the basics of Swing, case in point...

Within the constructor of `GalzyTable2` you are doing...

```
JApplet app = new JApplet();
add(app);
app.init();
app.start();
```

...Why are you adding another applet to an applet??

Case in point...

Within the `main` method, you are trying to add the instance of `JFrame` to itself...

```
f.getContentPane().add(f, button2);
```

Instead, create yourself a class that extends from something like `JPanel`, add your UI logical to this, using compound components if required.

Then, add this panel to whatever top level container you need.

Take the time to read through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GalaxyTable2 extends JPanel {

    private static final int PREF_W = 700;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;

    String[] columnNames
                    = {"Phone Name", "Brief Description", "Picture", "price",
                        "Buy"};

// Create image icons
    ImageIcon Image1 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s1.png"));
    ImageIcon Image2 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s2.png"));
    ImageIcon Image3 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s3.png"));
    ImageIcon Image4 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("s4.png"));
    ImageIcon Image5 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note.png"));
    ImageIcon Image6 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note2.png"));
    ImageIcon Image7 = new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("note3.png"));

    Object[][] rowData = {
        {"Galaxy S", "3G Support,CPU 1GHz",
            Image1, 120, false},
        {"Galaxy S II", "3G Support,CPU 1.2GHz",
            Image2, 170, false},
        {"Galaxy S III", "3G Support,CPU 1.4GHz",
            Image3, 205, false},
        {"Galaxy S4", "4G Support,CPU 1.6GHz",
            Image4, 230, false},
        {"Galaxy Note", "4G Support,CPU 1.4GHz",
            Image5, 190, false},
        {"Galaxy Note2 II", "4G Support,CPU 1.6GHz",
            Image6, 190, false},
        {"Galaxy Note 3", "4G Support,CPU 2.3GHz",
            Image7, 260, false},};

    MyTable ss = new MyTable(
                    rowData, columnNames);

    // Create a table
    JTable jTable1 = new JTable(ss);

    public GalaxyTable2() {
        jTable1.setRowHeight(70);

        add(new JScrollPane(jTable1),
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();

        JButton button = new JButton("Home");
        buttons.add(button);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Confirm");
        buttons.add(button2);

        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new AMainFrame7().setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new GalaxyTable2());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You also seem to have a lack of understanding about how to use layout managers.

Take the time to read through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Laying components out in a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: I used `f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`the problem is still. When I call no window appear.

Comment: @lovingjava You need to add the applet to the frame and not close the frame as a minimum.

Comment: That's not my point, my point is, you shouldn't be trying to do this in the first place...

Comment: I edited and now works fine still one problem which is the buttons does not appear. see the `updated` code.

Comment: In the constructor of `GalaxyTable2`, you creating a second frame, but `GalaxyTable2` already extends from `JFrame`...make `GalaxyTable2` extend from `JPanel`, in the `main` method create and instance of a `JFrame` and add you panel to it...

Comment: Could u plz show me in codes, Because I tried many ways and now I got confused